# Wordpress bug and errors

Tags: wordpress

I have a site that is almost fixed, but I'm having some errors... So I tried to reinstall the theme but Wordpress remembers all the settings from before (header, etc)... The problem that caused this to happen is that the site has a white bar on the side that doesn't need to be there, and it shrinks the site in half... Both on my laptop, desktop and iphone. Also, the slider doesn't display my featured slides. I get this error at the top of the page when trying to add a new slider:

> Notice: wp_deregister_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/setli/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2944

[Here](http://setlistshow.com/)'s the site in question.

I'll hire someone to help me get this fixed asap and pay you via Paypal.

Comment: Does Wordpress run correctly when you have the default theme `Twenty Twelve` active? What theme is installed? Your images aren't showing because they're looking for a cached image, which was probably deleted when you uninstalled the theme. Have you tried completely deleting the theme (and all of its files) directly from the server (via FTP, cPanel, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a large image (1600px wide) in your navigation area at the top of the page. This image is causing the entire site to get pushed outward and offset the containing `div`.

You need to add this to your CSS to fix:

```
#logo {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As for the error you put in your question, I do not see that anywhere. I would suggest completely deleting your theme from the server, and then download/install it again. Have you updated the theme recently? When did these issues start occurring?

Also, it looks like two themes are being using. Are you using a framework and a child theme? Try changing/disabling the child theme.

Answer (score 0):

Quote:

> Notice: wp_deregister_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and
>   styles should not be registered or enqueued until the
>   wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks.

Are you calling the function containing `wp_deregister_script` directly? Those functions should be called by using [actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Instead of calling that function directly, you should use `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function_name');` to run that function.

You use `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_enqueue_script` if the script is meant for the WordPress dashboard.

**Read more:**

[admin_enqueue_scripts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)

[wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)